# How can I compensate for the lack of work experience as an international Masters degree student in the United States?

Tags: internship, work-experience, united-states

I am studying for a Masters in Computer Science in the United States as an international student. My problem is I don't have work experience. I searched with no luck. I want to know how I can find an internship or a job.

How can I compensate for the lack of work experience?

Comment: Hey mohamed, and welcome to [workplace.se]! Could you give your post an [edit] to more clearly explain what it is you are having trouble with in specific? You say you want to compensate for a lack of work experience, but you also mention being an international student, and having trouble searching. What is the problem you are facing, what is causing it, and what do you want to have help with? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can compensate it easily just with an academic degree. It's a fundamental and (very) important part of your education in my eyes - but nothing less, nothing more.

In europe - especially germany - it's common to show "experience" with projects made at your university and private (programming) projects, when you're a freshman in the private sector; show what you've done in your bachelor/master thesis. But it's difficult to find a (good) payed job only with your degree.

Good luck!